# Intermittent DB connection failure

Tags: sql-server-2008

Recently I started to see intermittent errors in log files of my web application.
Raising from different places of the application the error is always about failed connection to DB which is located on another server:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

----

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
```

OR

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.

----

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   ....
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

I ran an infinite ping to DB server and another ping to google on my APP server. More than 24h have passed but logs do not show any network issues.

Any ideas why it happens?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) 10.50.4000.0 on Win Server 2008 R2

**Update:**

1 Database Autoclose is set to **OFF**

2 I have checked event logs of both APP and DB server and didn't find anything related to sqlserver or network errors. Event log however contains Schannel errors, but from I googled it is not related.

Comment: Check sql server error log + Windows Event log. Also, make sure that the database is **NOT** set to autoclose.

Comment: Is this a default instance or a named instance?

Comment: @Tom V Not sure how to check exactly, but it is the only instance on the server and the name is MSSQLSERVER